# GoogleInteractiveMediaAds issue when app came from background to foreground mode after Learn More option in ad was getting selected

Tags: ios, ads, google-ima

I am using latest **GoogleInteractiveMediaAds V3.11.1** in my app. After ad was getting loaded, I selected learn more option and moved the app to background and reopened the app once in the foreground at that time the below issue happens and my app struck for a while and I could not able to access my app at all.

> **Error Log :** void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
>   failed to return after waiting 10.000000 seconds. main run loop mode:
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Is there any way to fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

**Note :** The same issue exists in the GoogleInteractiveMedia sample source(Basic Source example) as well. Issue exists only in iOS 13 devices rest other below versions are working fine.

Comment: Which part of your app is causing this?

Comment: In my custom video player class while ad was getting loaded I have selected learn more option, in that scenario this happens.

Comment: I mean, which line of your app code causes this.  Your question needs to have more information for us to be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: That thing is not handled by us all the things are handled internally by  GoogleInteractiveMediaAds framework and I have not coded anything specifically. The issue exists only if I move app to background after selecting learn more option in the ad screen.

Comment: Note : The same issue exists in the GoogleInteractiveMedia sample source(Basic Source example) as well.

Comment: Issue exists only in iOS 13 devices below versions are working fine.

Comment: I recommend that you edit all your comments into your answer, since that would make it a really good question.